# Android nativeGetString crash on API 19

Tags: android

*(I'm answering this question for future reference if anyone runs into this silly problem.)*

I got this exception

```
07-05 17:23:49.499 1765-1765/? I/dalvikvm:   #16  pc 00030ec8  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
      #17  pc 0002e560  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+184)
      #18  pc 00063794  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+335)
      #19  pc 0004ce96  /system/lib/libdvm.so
      #20  pc 0004defc  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
      #21  pc 0004ec56  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::start(char const*, char const*)+353)
      #22  pc 0000109a  /system/bin/app_process
      #23  pc 0000e558  /system/lib/libc.so (__libc_init+47)
        at android.content.res.StringBlock.nativeGetString(Native Method)
        at android.content.res.StringBlock.get(StringBlock.java:82)
        at android.content.res.AssetManager.getResourceText(AssetManager.java:162)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:241)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getString(Resources.java:331)
        at android.content.Context.getString(Context.java:358)
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it works on newer devices, on old devices (API 19, for example), you cannot have emojis as a string resource.

The offending string was:

```
<string formatted="false" name="common_errors_title_unexpected">OH NOES! </string>
```

Removing the emoji fixed the issue.